# How to fix this syntax error that occurs when creating table in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I was trying to create a table in a SQL Server database but I am getting syntax error.

```
String quary1 = "CREATE TABLE " +chatTable + 
                "("
                +"From varchar(255),"
                +"To varchar(255),"
                +"Message varchar(255))";

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(quary1, con);
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It gives an error message

> Syntax error near From.

If u give me a hint will give a solution. Thank you

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: `From` is a T-SQL keyword - don't use it for your column names! (same goes for `To`) - use something more expressive !

Comment: @CMKhaledSaifullah please select one of the posts as the correct answer since a comment does not provide the reputation points and the the question remains as unanswered

Comment: I would change my column names to something like 'messageFrom', 'messageTo', and 'messageBody'

Comment: Ugh, this is a terrible design. Why do you think you need a table per chat, rather than a single table keyed off of ChatID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`From` is a reserve word](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) . replace it with `[From]`.

Its better if you can rename your column to more descriptive name like `FromAddress` etc

*Do the same with `TO` since it is also a reserve word.*

Answer (score 3):

Since **FROM** and **TO** are reserved word your need to change your query like this

```
String quary1 = "CREATE TABLE " +chatTable + 
                "("
                +"chatFrom varchar(255),"
                +"chatTo varchar(255),"
                +"Message varchar(255))";
```

To see a complete list of all the Reserved Word see this link

**http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx**

Answer (score 2):

`FROM` and `TO` are a [*reserved keywords*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in T-SQL. Use them with square brackets like `[FROM]` and `[TO]`

As a general suggestion, use different column names instead `;)`

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

```
String quary1 = "CREATE TABLE " +chatTable + 
                "("
                +"[From] varchar(255),"
                +"[To] varchar(255),"
                +"[Message] varchar(255))";

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(quary1, con);
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```